# How do I use a comparison operator to yield a 0 or 1 in an arithmetic expression?

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

I have a SQL statement that defines a variable using an arithmetic expression.  It runs fine in some settings but not in others.  I am relying on `(t1.x > 20)` resolving to either 0 or 1.

```
create table top2 as
select t1.x as x1, 3+(t1.x>20) as x2
from top1 t1;
```

This runs fine in SAS, but fails in Oracle.  Is there some way to express it better so that it will run in either setting?

Comment: Can x be a negative number?

Comment: Oracle has no Boolean datatype (which may be implicitly converted to number in the above case), so `x > 20` is not an [expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/About-SQL-Expressions.html#GUID-68789A5C-B142-496F-ADEE-837F75F95B2B). The only way to implement Boolean-like handling is to use `case` expression

Comment: @PhilCoulson - Yes, it can be a negative number.

Comment: @astentx - I was afraid that would be the case (no pun intended).

Comment: If you want something that will work with minimal changes both in Oracle and in SAS (I have only heard of SAS, I don't know anything about it), you **can** rewrite it, but how to do that depends on your exact expression. For example, for the very specific expression you wrote, you could replace it with `greatest(0, sign(x-20))`. Even then, though, perhaps the **sign** function in SAS is called **sgn**, and/or **greatest** in SAS may simply be **max** - in SQL **max** has a different meaning as an aggregate function.

Answer (score 4):

```
3 + case when t1.x > 20 then 1 else 0 end as x2
```

(note that you have `as t1.x2`, but when you give an alias, that can't be qualified with a table or view name/alias).

The `case` expression will evaluate to 0, too, when `t1.x` is `null`; if a different handling is desired (for example you may want to return `null` in that case), that can be arranged too. For you to specify the desired behavior.

Comment: Or may as well simplify to `case when t1.x>20 then 4 else 3 end as x2`

Comment: @Reeza - true; but if the magic number `3` has meaning in the OP's problem, and the overall sum comes from two unrelated places (the magic number `3` means one thing, the marker 0 or 1 from the condition is unrelated to the magic number), then leaving the code as is will make it a lot easier for future developers to understand what the code is intended to do. Writing it your way will obscure that somewhat.

Comment: I adjusted the code in the question to deal with the alias issue.  The actual calculation is significantly more complicated, so I was hoping to avoid case expressions.  However, you have embedded the case expression within the calculation, which I didn't know was even an option.

Comment: @PauldeBarros - a `case` expression is, as the name implies, an expression. It can be used anywhere an expression can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with case expression too, but throwing this out there to both answer your question and demonstrate how **not** using a case expression might obscure the logic you're trying to implement. Up to you!

**Using joins**

```
create table top2 as
select t1.x as x1, 3 + coalesce(b.num/20,0) as x2
from top1 t1
left join (select 20 as x) t2 on t1.x>t2.x
```

**Using basic SQL functions**

```
create table top2 as
select t1.x as x1, 3 + floor(((coalesce(nullif(t1.x,20),0)/20)+1)/2) as x2
from top1 t1;
```